# C# ASP.NET API - RestSharp

Tags: c#, api

I am using an get request to receive some data from an asp .net API but having some problems with german umlauts like ä,ö, and encoding formats. In my c# form the result is displayed as some symbol like in the image below.

I've tried several things but cannot fix it. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance.

```
//API Request
var client = new RestClient(ServerIP);

client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);


request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");

//User
request.AddParameter("User", toolStripUserLabel);

//Client - Response
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

var json = response.Content;
MessageBox.Show(json);
```

[image]

Comment: Does the server deliver correct utf-8 in the response (that is actually a must for json) ? If yes you might try to read the raw bytes from the response and do the utf-8 Encoding yourself. If not fix the server or also do the encoding from the raw bytes yourself with the encoding the server is delivering.

Comment: Something like "var json = Encoding.Utf8.GetString(response.RawBytes);"

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

1) If I am trying to receive the response with postman everything looks god. But maybe postman is converting the results? 
2) I've tried with your suggestion but got the same result.

Comment: Is the actual result faulty or is it only the display? Have you tried to ... maybe just write the result to a file and open with some unicode capable text editor? If it's correct there, then I'd investigate your UI component / used font.

Comment: It is not only in the ui, I wrote it to a textfile and the result is the same. Also if I am going to save it again. I think it's a problem with the response..

Comment: I have now tested a little bit more. I have 2 IIS installations, at one of them I have no troubles. So it must be the IIS configuration. I have already checked globalization settings but havent found the problem yet. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!